# Visual Studio remote debugging authentication issue

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I want to debug on a virtual machine.
I installed the Visual Studio remote debugger and without authentication, it works.
But due to security reasons, I want to use the option "Remote with Windows authentication".
So, using the "Visual Studio Remote debugger", I select Tools->Permissions, then I click Add and
a window appears to select Users or Groups.
The problem is, that in "Locations" I can see only the virtual machine name and can not select another machine.

In MyComputer->Network(on the virtual machine), I see both machines - the virtual and my main machine(from where I will perform the debug), so it is visible in the network by default.

I tried to force it with a command line argument like this:
msvsmon.exe /allow UserName@MachineName,
but it shows a message, that such user can not be found.

Does anybody know what should be done to make this tool working?

Comment: My problem was, that I got no prompt for username and password.
So just I tried many times to start the debug and sometimes the prompt appears. 
This is the solution - just try many times, until the window appears.
Don`t know how to mark this question as solved.